# Refused to display 'https://example.com/app/appName' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny' in Shopify

Tags: nginx, iframe, shopify, x-frame-options, shopify-app

I unable to open my embedded app in Shopify, it throws error as

> Refused to display 'https://example.com/app/appName' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

I am using nginx version 1.10 and I have tried to use the following in ngiinx.conf file but even I receive the same error

> add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
>
> add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://subdomain.example.com/"
>
> proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;

when I tried this command it shows X-Frame-Options: DENY

> curl -v https://example.com/app/appName

someone can guide me to get me out of this error

Answer (score 0):

In your Shopify Partner dashboard, for the App you created, make sure you set the App to be **embedded**. If you have that set, then your App will render just fine in the Shopify iframe and you won't have this issue.

Comment: I am not sure that's an issue here. it should be embedded already. Because the app was running for a very long time. But in recent time, it's not working. Thanks @dave

Comment: Ok.. so yes.. you need to remove the bad headers from your embedded App that maybe someone turned back on in a configuration of your App.

Comment: Currently, After the embedded app failure, Once I refresh the Page, I could log in to the App. So, some parameter is an issue for the initial load.

Comment: There are countless things going on with browsers, cookies, headers and re-directs. Read up on the Safari 12 issue with EASDK apps to get a better handle on it.